# Created a temporary view in SQL and the table cells are filled with the column names and not the data

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I used this to create a new temporary view from a previous one and the resulting table ends up with all the cells being filled in with the column names and not the data. How can I fix this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW fireCallsDF AS (
  SELECT "Call_Type",
         "Fire_Prevention_District",
         "Neighborhooods_-_Analysis_Boundaries",
         "Number_of_Alarms",
         "Original_Priority",
         "Unit_Type",
         "Battalion",
         "Call_Type_Group"
  FROM fireCallsGroupCleaned);
```

Comment: The way to fix this is to learn that different implementations of SQL use different delimiters for (a) object names and (b) strings, and if you assume that double quotes mean the same thing between different dialects, you end up with problems like this, so research what your current dialect uses before writing code that makes a wrong assumption ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're just inserting strings into the table.  Try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW fireCallsDF AS (
  SELECT [Call_Type],
         [Fire_Prevention_District],
         [Neighborhooods_-_Analysis_Boundaries],
         [Number_of_Alarms],
         [Original_Priority],
         [Unit_Type],
         [Battalion],
         [Call_Type_Group]
  FROM fireCallsGroupCleaned);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, no need to quote the column names or bracket them. But this column *Neighborhooods_-_Analysis_Boundaries* might cause problems. More proper naming for the column in the previous view, without the - in between the underscores.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW fireCallsDF AS (
  SELECT Call_Type,
         Fire_Prevention_District,
         Neighborhooods_Analysis_Boundaries, -- rename in previous view
         Number_of_Alarms,
         Original_Priority,
         Unit_Type,
         Battalion,
         Call_Type_Group
  FROM fireCallsGroupCleaned);
```

Comment: The hyphen is a special character, hence my use of square brackets, more a safety mechanism.  I agree, however, that naming the fields properly in the first case is the best approach.